# Get latest date before date value in row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using MSSQL 2008 R2. I am attempting to get the latest data date up to a date stored in another column.  I am able to pull the latest data date overall using max(ProcedureDate) in a subquery; however, i need the latest date before the date that's stored in the column.

Here's an example:

```
Current Table: Procedures       

ID Patient  ProcedureType   ProcedureDate
1  George   ExamA           1/1/2013
2  George   TreatmentA      1/3/2013
2  George   TreatmentB      1/5/2003
4  George   ExamB           2/1/2013
5  George   TreatmentA      2/5/2013

Desired Table:  ProceduresWithLastExam

ID Patient  ProcedureType   ProcedureDate   LastExamDate    DaysSinceLastExam    LastExamType
1  George   ExamA           1/1/2013        1/1/2013        0                    ExamA
2  George   TreatmentA      1/3/2013        1/1/2013        2                    ExamA
3  George   TreatmentB      1/5/2013        1/1/2013        4                    ExamA
4  George   ExamB           2/1/2013        2/1/2013        0                    ExamB
5  George   TreatmentA      2/5/2013        2/1/2013        4                    ExamB
```

I have attempted using the following, but it only pulls back the latest data date for that Patient.

```
select p.*, a.LastExamDate, a.ProcedureType as LastExamType from Procedures p
left join (
   select exams.Patient, exams.ProcedureType, MAX(exams.ProcedureDate) as LastExamDate from Procedures exams
   where ProcedureType like 'Exam%'
   group by exams.Patient, exams.ProcedureType
)a
on p.Patient = a.Patient
```

The results for all rows is 2/1/13 as LastExamDate and ExamB as LastExamType.

I have attempted including some additional date parameters in my left join, in my where clause, and in my subquery to no success.

Please note I have omitted datediff logic until I can get the correct dates to return.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [OUTER APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). It is like a correlated subquery but allows multiple columns:

```
SELECT  p.ID, 
        p.Patient,
        p.ProcedureType,
        p.ProcedureDate,
        [LastExamDate] = exam.ProcedureDate, 
        [DaysSinceLastExam] = DATEDIFF(DAY, exam.ProcedureDate, p.ProcedureDate),
        [LastExamType] = exam.ProcedureType 
FROM    Procedures p
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 exams.ProcedureType, exams.ProcedureDate
            FROM    Procedures exams
            WHERE   Exams.ProcedureType LIKE '%Exam%'
            AND     Exams.Patient = p.Patient
            AND     Exams.ProcedureDate <= p.ProcedureDate
            ORDER BY Exams.ProcedureDate DESC
        ) exam;
```

**[Example On SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/28f6f/1)**

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT  A.*, 
        B.ProcedureDate LastExamDate, 
        DATEDIFF(DAY,B.ProcedureDate,A.ProcedureDate) DaysSinceLastExam,
        B.ProcedureType
FROM Procedures A
OUTER APPLY (   SELECT TOP 1 *
                FROM Procedures
                WHERE Patient = A.Patient 
                AND ProcedureDate <= A.ProcedureDate
                AND ProcedureType LIKE 'Exam%'
                ORDER BY ProcedureDate DESC) B
```

Here is a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4d40f/1) for you to try.