# How to get the latest value and the one right before that

Tags: sql

I was reviewing this question/answer
[Get latest date before date value in row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895910/get-latest-date-before-date-value-in-row)
I thought I would give it a try, but every time I try the 'outer apply'

```
I get an error:  Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

In my query, my 'from' statement is not as simple as the example in the question & answer.
My 'from' has multiple joins and then at the every end of my joins I'm trying this:

```
outer apply
(
SELECT top 1 * 
    from <mytable>
    where <mytable.column> in ('1','3')
)
```

Any additional help is much appreciated
I'm using SQLserver 2008 R2

Comment: You'll need to post your entire query. I don't think we can track down a syntax error without it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you alias your outer apply. I don't know why SQL Server is always so unhelpful with this error.

```
outer apply
(
SELECT top 1 * 
    from <mytable>
    where <mytable.column> in ('1','3')
) AS obligatory_alias
```

Answer (score 0):

I would actually do something like the following

```
select ColumnsFromTableAYouCareAbout, max(b.datecolumn) as lastdate from mytable a
inner join mytable b on b.datecolumn < a.datecolumn
group by ColumnsFromTableAYouCareAbout
```